# put-gateway-response fails when --response-parameters option is set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to set some custom API Gateway responses using aws cli. This is the command I'm using (only the related parameter):

```
aws apigateway put-gateway-response --response-parameters method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin='"'"'*'"'"'
```

The complete command is:

> aws apigateway put-gateway-response --rest-api-id w1s3nc4dxd --response-type UNAUTHORIZED --status-code 401 --response-parameters method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin='"'"'*'"'"' --response-templates '{ "application/json": "{\"errorcode\":401,\"message\":$context.error.messageString}" }' --region eu-west-1

And it fails with:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the PutGatewayResponse operation: Invalid mapping expression specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid mapping expression specified: method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin]

If it is executed without that param, everything works properly. I have also tried with the json format and same result.

```
--response-parameters '{"method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"'"'*'"'"}'
```

Any insight? Thanks in advance.

--- EDIT

Just for an extra clarification. This fails with all kind of response-parameters, this is not only involving Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: did you enable CORS?

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure why is CORS related with this. Some of my end points has CORS enabled while others not. Just trying to set a header to the API Gateway Response. To make it clearer, it fails no matter what the response parameter is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the format for Gateway Response parameters should be `gatewayresponse.header.[name]`. That will be the map key (destination), and the value (source) is either a static value (like you have) or a mapping expression to `method.request.(path|querystring|header).[name]` or `stageVariables.[name]` or `context.[name]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`--response-parameters '{"gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"'"'*'"'"}'`, it worked for me